# curl_init keep returning error

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, curl

I'm trying to run a script on my server, but i keep getting below error. i've tried to install cURL, which seem to be installed when i run `curl -V`, but i still get the error. What do i need to do in order to get this to work.

**Error**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in /var/www/html/index.php:4\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 4
```

**line 4**

```
$curl = curl_init();
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php5-curl` - And please delete your question

Comment: E: Unable to locate package php5-curl

Comment: I think that you also have to enable it in the php.ini file.

Comment: What version of ubuntu?

Comment: I think it's called php-curl on Ubuntu 16.04 - try `sudo apt-get install php-curl`